# How come my MacBook Air won't let me sign in to my apple ID?

Tags: mac-appstore

I just got a new MacBook Air and I was in App Store, trying to download some stuff. But then, it tells me to sign in to my Apple ID, so I did. But it tells me to review my account information and I did. And then it tells me to do that again and again. What should I do?

Comment: Could you be more specific on the error message or share a screenshot?

Comment: Did you try reentering credit card info?

Comment: Which version of MacOS? Which model of MBA?